# How can I run a phpunit test using composer on windows(cmd)

Tags: php, windows, phpunit, composer-php

I want to run a phpunit test on my local windows machine..(using wamp)..

I have globally installed composer..And phpunit is installed on my local directory..

Folder Structure..

```
_________tests
|          |
|          |______PagesTest.php
|
|________vendor
           |
           |______bin
                   |
                   |_____phpunit
```

On my localroot(www)..I have created a phpunit.xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        backupStaticAttributes="false"
        processIsolation="false"
        stopOnFailure="false"
        backupGlobals="false"
        syntaxCheck="false"
        colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Punta Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

On Cmd I tried:

```
C:\wamp\www\vendor\bin>phpunit PagesTest
```

The output is

```
Cannot open file PagesTest.php
```

And I have no idea how can i run this PagesTest.php file using composer

Comment: Have you configured phpunit.xml to use the autoloader?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, PHPUnit is running, but doesn't find the Test file, because the Composer Autoloader isn't loaded.

You can solve this, by adding a configuration file for PHPUnit, which defines the attribute `bootstrap` and set the Composer Autoloader file.

Example for `phpunit.xml.dist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="My Project - TestSuite">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

Then simply run the PHPUnit command:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

On Windows just flip the slashes: `C:\> .\vendor\bin\phpunit`

PHPUnit will automatically detect the configuration file (`phpunit.xml.dist`) and load the Composer Autoloader during its bootstrap phase.

Comment: Thanks i have a xml file totally forgot about..And missed the bootstrap..But i'm on windows (wamp)(cmd)..vendor/bin/phpunit command doesnt work..which maybe  a composer bug on windows..

Comment: Glad i could help. (On Windows just flip the slashes on the command `.\vendor\bin\phpunit.bat`. I've updated my answer.)

Comment: .\vendor\bin\phpunit works i accepted your answer..

Answer (score 3):

If the test class is located in a subdirectory, you need to pass the complete path to it like this:

```
phpunit ./tests/PagesTest.php
```

You can run `phpunit` without any argument which will execute all tests in the testsuite as it was configured in the `phpunit.xml.dist` or `phpunit.xml` file.

To use the `phpunit` binary install via Composer in your project, you need to use the path to it:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests/PagesTest.php
```

I do not have a Windows installation to test this, but maybe you have to prefix the call with `php` (like `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit`).

Comment: interestingly php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit solved my problem..